# Gantt Chart - Enable Event Lables

Tags: gantt-chart, palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Is it possible to display the event labels in the Gantt chart in Workshop? So far I only see the possibility if my layer has the event type "Time Range". But I would also like to display the labels for discrete events. It makes no sense to show a Gantt with discrete events without showing the labels for them. This is possible with hovering, but I also need it without hovering.

It would also be interesting if you could choose diamonds, squares or other shapes instead of circles.

I went through all the settings and also tried to adjust the Widget Configuration JSON, but that didn't help.